# I need to design a common emitter amplifier circuit using a voltage divider configuration.

Tags: voltage, amplifier, dc, gain, biasing

As mentioned in the title, I need help designing a common emitter amplifier circuit using a transistor.
I've been given some details:
-use 2N2222 transistor which hfe = 75
-Ic current = Ie current = 1.5mA
-Vce = 6v
-Vcc = 12v
-signal = 200 mVp-p
-Rsource = 1.5 Kohms
-The values for the capacitors were also recommended (10uF and 100uF as displayed)

I have been following tips like:
Ve = 1/10 Vcc

R2 is "< or =" to (Beta)*Re

Vb = [R2/(R1+R2)]Vcc

I have to obtain a signal coming from the load which will be measured with an oscilloscope. The signal has to be smooth like the source signal, but so far I'm getting a very distorted one regardless of my efforts to fix it.
I am attaching the pic of my current circuit.[image: current transistor values for my transistor amplifier design so far]

Keep in mind: Rc= collector resistance
              Re = emitter resistance
              Ic = Ie = collector and emitter currents respectively

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the waveform at the output? I suspect your circuit design is OK but you are overloading it. Is the requirement to accept a 200mV p-p input?

Comment: What AC gain do you want? Do you have to completely bypass \$R_E\$ with \$C_E\$? Are you allowed to make _any_ changes to the topology?

Answer (score 0):

The diode equation shows us the dramatic changes in current thru the emitter, as Vbe changes: 18milliVolt deltaVbe produces 2:1 delta Ie (and Ic); 60mV produces 10:1 delta Ie; 180mV produces 10^3 or 1,000:1.

Your task is to produce a linearized emitter behavior, where the additional resistance mostly swamps out the diode's exponential response; the working constant for describing the diode behavior is 0.026volts (k*t/q) and that tells us the DC voltage across the Remitter_external_discrete_RadioShack should be at least 0.2 volts so the 0.026 have only a *SMALL* effect on the linearity, the prettiness, of the output sinwave.

For easy CE design [if you have the VDD to consume], I implement first-pass successes using V_base_gnd of 1/3 of VDD.

If you are allowed, insert 2 resistors between emitter and GND; bypass one with a "big cap". Use the other resistor to provide the 200milliVolts (or bigger) linearizing effect; you use this resistor, unbypassed, to define the amps/volt behavior of the complete circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWggAB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>